# asp.net mvc3, why dataannotation validates without Validator Attributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I have a simple ViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This title field is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

here's my form based on  this View Model.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>ProductViewModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

I dont want to validate the price field.  but it got automatically validated, if nothing entered, will show this field is required.  I notice I use double for price. If I changed it to "string".  validation is removed.  why type "double" cause automatic validation?

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want to validate the price field. but it got automatically validated, if nothing entered, will show this field is required

Because a double is a value type, which cannot be null. If you want the value to allow not having a value, use a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) double: `double?` on your model:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This title field is required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because double is a value type, and cannot be null.  You could have made it `double?` or `Nullable<double>` and it would be fine.